# Substituting in arraylists

Tags: java

I have an hash map, which maps integers to array of ArrayLists. For example, my data structure is the following:

```
7->((7,5,**4,3,1**),(7,6,4,3,1))
4->((4,2,1),(4,3,1))
```

Here, 7 is key, and arraylist e.g is (7,5,4,3,1), the array of arraylist in turn is ((7,5,4,3,1),(7,6,4,3,1))

4 is key, and arraylist e.g. is (4,2,1), the array of arraylist in turn is ((4,2,1),(4,3,1))

I wish to substitute the key values (in any given arraylist) and the values following it to create other arraylists, one example of this is given below:

```
7->((7,5,**4,2,1**),(7,6,4,2,1),(7,5,4,3,1),(7,6,4,3,1))
```

**the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists**

the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists..i know the datastructure..but want to create arraylists by substitution as given in subsequent example

Is there someway in java programming by which I may achieve this?
I am a novice at Java programming...I thought long about this but could not move it...can someone please help

Comment: what are those stars (bold? no bold in code...).

Comment: ya they mean bold...i pressed control+b for bold and the stars appeared...the thing i wanted to emphasize was i know the datastructure..i know its a map of arraylists of arraylist...but i am not getting the substitution..that's what i wanted to emphasise.

Comment: But `ArrayList` is growable, so what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> map;
map = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>();
```

**EDIT**: I've used 2 lines so that my answer could be more readable.

Comment: I wish to substitute the key values (in any given arraylist) and the values following it to create other arraylists..i know about the datastructure..but the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists

Answer (score 1):

What actually do you want?

Is bellow code helpful?

```
Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> mapData = new HashMap<Integer, List<List<Integer>>>();

public void fillData(List<List<Integer>> lists)
{
    // provide any kind of list of list
    // e.g lists = {2,3,5,3}, {4,5,3,2}, {2,4,3}, {6,3,4}
    for(List<Integer> list : lists)
    {
        int mapKey = list.get(0);
        if(mapData.get(mapKey) == null)
        {
            // list of list will be null in first occurence of key(first element of list).
            // create list of list and put tat in map.
            List<List<Integer>> tempListOfList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
            tempListOfList.add(list);
            mapData.put(mapKey, tempListOfList);
        }
        else
        {
            // from second occurence of same key.
            // put list in the list of list of that key.
            List<List<Integer>> listOfListInMap = mapData.get(mapKey);
            listOfListInMap.add(list);
        }
    }
}

public List<List<Integer>> getListsByKey(int key)
{
    // get list of list by mapKey
    return mapData.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below should do it:

```
   Map<Integer, ArrayList <ArrayList<Integer>>> map = new hashMap<>();
```

Comment: the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists..i know the datastructure..but want to create arraylists by substitution as given in subsequent example

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>`.

Comment: the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists..i know the datastructure..but want to create arraylists by substitution as given in subsequent example

Answer (score 0):

You want to map integers to a list of lists of integers. This can be declared as:

```
Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<List<List<Integer>>>();
```

You can then put instances of `ArrayList<List<Integer>>` (or any other class that implements `List`) and for each such list of lists, you can add instances of `ArrayList<Integer>`.

You can then use the `List.subList()` method to put selected sublists into other entries in the map.

Say you have a list containing the two lists `(7,5,4,3,1)` and `(7,6,4,3,1)` stored under `7` and you want to construct the list of lists that should be stored under the key `4`. You can do this:

```
List<List<Integer>> sevens = map.get(7);
List<List<Integer>> fours = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
for (List<Integer> aSevenList : sevens) {
    int index = aSevenList.indexOf(4);
    if (index >= 0) {
        fours.add(aSevenList.subList(index, aSevenList.size()));
    }
}
map.put(4, fours);
```

If you want to substitute one list as part of another, the following code fragment shows how that might be done:

```
int[] vals = { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int val : vals) list.add(val);
List<Integer> sub = new ArrayList<Integer>();
sub.add(40);
sub.add(30);
sub.add(20);
System.out.println("Original list: " + list);
List<Integer> slice = list.subList(3, vals.length - 1);
slice.clear();
slice.addAll(sub);
System.out.println("Modified list: " + list);
```

This will generate the following output:

> Original list: [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>   Modified list: [7, 6, 5, 40, 30, 20, 1]

Note that changes to a sublist are propagated to the original list.

Comment: the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists..i know the datastructure..but want to create arraylists by substitution as given in subsequent example

Comment: @user1593063 - I updated the answer to show how it might work for you.

Comment: actually i want to make appropriate substitution in sevens list and not 4s list

Comment: also thanks for helping...but sorry my problem is about 7s list

Comment: @user1593063 - So the problem statement is: given a pair of lists and a list of lists, scan the list of lists and for each element that has a sublist that equals the first element of the pair, substitute the second element of the pair for the match?

Comment: @user1593063 - I provided a code fragment that shows how you can do the substitution. The matching part is a different problem; let me know if you need help with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a List of Lists and store this as part of a Map data structure. One possible way would be as follows:

```
Map<Integer,List<List<Integer>>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<List<Integer>>>();

//How to add
List<List<Integer>> list = map.get(your_key);
if(list == null){ //This should be for the first time you're accessing the map with the key
 list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
}
//Create a inner list which will store the list of numbers
ArrayList<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
innerList.add(integer_values);

//Add inner list to the list of lists
list.add(innerList);

//Finally put the list of list into the map with the key
map.put(your_key, list);
```

**Edit:** Assuming you know index of the list where you want to add new elements:

```
//Adding numbers to the inner list - assume you know the index 
List<List<Integer>> list = map.get(key);
if(list == null || list.size() >= index){ //There's no list against the key or the size of the list is less then the index requested
 return;
}

//Add new elements to the inner list
List<Integer> innerList = list.get(index);
innerList.add(your_new_int_values);

//Add inner list to the list of lists
list.add(innerList);

//Finally put the list of list into the map with the key
map.put(key, list);
```

Comment: the thing I am not getting is how to obtain this substitution....to create bigger arraylists..i know the datastructure..but want to create arraylists by substitution as given in subsequent example